# DRF 'ObtainAuthToken' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am getting an error every time the user login. The function should show the Token associated with the user, but I am getting an error message 'ObtainAuthToken' object that has no attribute 'request'.

**Views.py**

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.serializers import AuthTokenSerializer
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken

class LoginView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer
    
    def create(self, request):
        return ObtainAuthToken().post(request)
```

**Installed App**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    'core',
    
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class LoginView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        return ObtainAuthToken().as_view()(request=request._request)
```

This would be work for you

Comment: Could you provide an explanation why it should be this way? I am new to DRF and I would liek to understand this